# How to compare a double value to a decimal from database and if they are alike, then return true

Tags: android, mysql, sql

Example:

Database latitude value: 33.3360705

location from android device latitude value: 33.33607

These are technically NOT the same, BUT the difference is so little that I would like to consider them the same.

How would I do that? :)

Thanks.

Comment: What database?  Onboard SQLite?  Server MySQL? And how is it stored in the DB?  As a Real?  As text?  (Don't laugh, I've seen people do that!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `ROUND` in MySQL when getting the value from the database. The following will round to 5 decimal places (which matches your android device value):

```
SELECT ROUND(myValue, 5) 
FROM myTable
```